# django rest framework does not show utf8 words

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

According to the this [post](http://www.sitepoint.com/building-simple-rest-api-mobile-applications/) , i want to make a rest api for my android application . but when i wan give json from the django rest framework , it's not support utf8 words.
this is screenshot :

[image]

this is my model :

```
    from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models
class News(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    created = models.DateTimeField('auto_now_add = True')
    active = models.BooleanField()

    def __str__(self):
        return  self.title.encode('utf8')
```

this is my view :

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework import permissions
from news.models import News
from news.serializers import NewsSerialzer

class NewsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = News.objects.all()
    serializer_class = NewsSerialzer
```

and this is my serializers:

```
from news.models import News
from rest_framework import serializers

class NewsSerialzer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = News
        fields  = ('title' , 'active' , 'created')
```

i use django rest framework 3.3.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyway , when i see `json` in the chrome +33 , response does not show `utf8` word but when i see response in the Firefox every thing is Ok , and when i parse the `Json` every thing is Ok .

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with `self.title.encode('utf8')`. Seems like your are using python 2. The `encode()` function converts string to bytes. That's why title is getting weird. Since you are already importing `unicode_literals` from `__future__`, all the string will be unicode. Just return `self.title` that would solve the problem.. For more info  https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that u assign correct encoding to http header so browser will recognize encoding of data. 
Example below show how u can identify it using Developer Tool in Firefox. Same tools exists in Chrome . If u clearly will not assign encoding in header then browser will try guest or use default to encode data from server.

[image]